# How change the format Weight in Magento?

Tags: phtml

How does one round the value of a weight down to a whole number? Currently my product pages show weight with many digits after the decimal point:
[image]

I want it to be like so:
[image]

This is my code in `price.phtml`:

```
<span class="regular-weight"> <?php $pro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId()); ?>
                 <?php echo  $pro->getWeight(); ?><?php echo $this->__('grams');?>
            </span>
```

Comment: Did you try explode function of php. you can explode it easily. Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php or http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<span class="regular-weight"> <?php $pro=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId()); ?>
    <?php    
        $weight = (float) $pro->getWeight();
        $formattedWeight = number_format($weight, 0, ',', '');
        echo sprintf("%s %s", $formattedWeight, $this->__('grams'));
    ?>
</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$_MyValue = $pro->getWeight();
if (is_numeric($_MyValue))
{
 $my_data_value = number_format((float)$_MyValue, 0, '.', '');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
<span class="regular-weight">
     <?php echo number_format($_product->getWeight())?><?php echo $this->__('grams');?>
</span>
```

**OR**

```
<span class="regular-weight">
     <?php echo round($_product->getWeight())?><?php echo $this->__('grams');?>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

In database, weight attribute have backend_type set to decimal.

To change the decimal precision of attributes that have a backend_type set to decimal,

You have to change the type of value in this table :

```
catalog_product_entity_decimal
```

If you have not change yet, you should see :

```
decimal(12,4)
```

In your case, you have to replace with

```
decimal(12,0)
```